# Rails and Git push, Git pull: logs return same commit, changes aren't made

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

I've got a local branch (`master`), a GitHub repo (`origin`), and another remote repo (`server`). I've set up my remote so locally I can type `git push server master` and push the changes to `server/master`.

When I type `git log -1` locally and on the server they return the same commit, but none of the changes I made locally are visible on the server.

I deployed my app with Capistrano so redeploying it makes the changes visible immediately, but I don't want to have to redeploy every time I make a change.

Any idea what's going on here? I'm rather new to Git. Hopefully it's something easy to fix.

Comment: First, `master` is a local **branch** and not a repo. Similarly you have `origin/master` and `server/master` as remote branches. Are you sure that you are pushing local commits to the `server/master` branch? If yes, maybe the server has a different branch checked out. Can you connect to the `server` machine and try `git branch` to see which branch is currently checked out.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah, forgive my terminology. Learning curve and all. And `git branch` on the server returns `master`.

Comment: ok, might sound like a stupid question. but did you commit the changes locally (to `master` branch) before pushing to `server` repo. In other words does the latest commit (`git log -1`) contain the changes you made?

Comment: What do you see after each of steps 1 and 4 below: (1) `git checkout master && git log -1` locally and on the server. (2) make a local change, stage it, and commit it. (3) do a `git push server master`. (4) `git checkout master && git log -1` locally and on the server.

Comment: @mtariq Yeah, `git log -1` does have the latest commit. The changes themselves though don't show up.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta `git co` is not a command.

Comment: @mileorsohigh ah sorry, I meant `checkout`, I'm just used to using `co` as an alias

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Locally I see `M config/deploy.rb Already on 'master'` and remotely I see `Switched to branch 'master'`. Does that mean that it worked?

Comment: I guess I was more curious about the result of `git log -1`.  So basically do a `git log -1` locally and on the server, making sure you're on the master branch of each repo before doing so (this is accomplished by a `git checkout master` on each repo).  Ideally, you will see the same commit for both.  Then make a change locally (on master branch), be sure to stage it, and commit it (with message "test", let's say).  Then `git push server master`, and do the same thing of checking `git log -1` on both the local and `server` masters.  You should see the same commit on both, with message "test".

Comment: Alright, I've realised that my `server` branch was pointing to the `app.git` folder, but the site itself is in a folder called `current` in `app.git`. A hangover from Capistrano it seems. But the `git log -1` in `app.git` returns the latest commit, but `git log -1` in `current` returns the last Capistrano deploy.

Is there anything I can do without redeploying the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you maybe looking at a different directory than your web server is pointed to.

When I setup capistrano:

```
cap deploy:setup
#then
cap deploy
```

it creates a directory structure similar to:

```
/releases (each deploy gets its own randome number directory)
/current (a sym-link to the latest release)
/shared
```

None of these folder are tied to git.  Which makes me think your webserver may not be pointed to the same directory that you're using with git.

--

You may find cap deploy is preferable as you'll be able to see the output if there are any issues.

I'm not a huge expert but the above is how I've setup rails with Capistrano.

Comment: That does make a bit of sense. Can I tie one of the Capistrano deploys to Git from this point?

Comment: no, all the git structure is removed. You should maybe see what directory your webserver is pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `origin` is the name used for the GitHub remote and not `master`. You can check what remotes you have by doing `git remote show`. If you want even more detail on the remote use `git remote show origin` (or whatever your remote is called, if it is not origin). This will give you a list. I suspect that what you have is actually two local branches (master and server). Try doing a `git push server origin`. This will take your server branch and put it on GitHub.

**Alternatively**

If you are trying to combine the changes in your server branch with your master branch then use `checkout master` and then `git merge server`. This will merge your changes from the server branch into your master branch and you can then upload to GitHub via `git push master origin`.

Comment: Yeah, `master` is local, `origin` is GitHub.